# searchBar in titleView of navigationItem disappears while app goes to background

Tags: ios, swift

```
lazy var searchBar = UISearchBar(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 
self.view.bounds.width - 50, height: 30))

searchBar.delegate = self
searchBar.sizeToFit()
navigationBar.topItem?.titleView = searchBar
```

A navigation bar in storyboard design has search bar which is made hidden on pushing the viewController, navigation bar on storyboard design is shown when presenting VC. While pushing VC, setting the same search bar to

```
self.navigationItem.titleView = searchBar
```

also tried,

```
navigationController?.navigationBar.topItem?.titleView = searchBar
```

titleView displays on viewDidLoad() and viewDidAppear(), but when entered background and returned back to app the search bar disappears.

Answer (score 0):

Use `UISearchController` for `UISearchBar`. Like,

```
class ViewController: UITableViewController, UISearchResultsUpdating {

    let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
        self.definesPresentationContext = true

        // Place the search bar in the navigation item's title view.
        self.navigationItem.titleView = searchController.searchBar

        // Don't hide the navigation bar because the search bar is in it.
        searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false
    }
}
```

You can get more Information [here](https://riptutorial.com/ios/example/9505/search-bar-in-navigation-bar-title).

I hope this will help you.

Comment: Thank you, for your answer. But again same issue. The searchBar actually present in the navigation bar when i return back to the app. I can able to edit and search in the searchBar but it's not visible.

Comment: You can follow the link which i added in my answer for adding searchBar in navigation bar. You may solve your issue if not solved then it is not search bar issue. You have to debug for another issue. @Kamalraj